# multiple case statements with same logic in when

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use case statement for each column in mysql. The logic inside when of each case statement is same which is a long list. Is there a way to write this optimally. like

```
case  when cond1 
          then 'xyz'  as col1, 
               'xyz2' as col2, 
               'uuy'  as col3 
         else   null 
for all each column end.
```

Comment: first let clear what's your need in ouput i.e. what data needed in ouput? and what is the structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: No

Long Answer: Kind of. You can play with either wrapping the logic into function and then call it for each column (if applicable) or play with dynamic query - dirty but will work.
Consider this:

```
create table t (
 alef varchar(100),
 bet varchar(100));

set @case := 'case when ''?'' = ''A'' then 1 else 0 end';

set @sql := concat('select ',replace(@case,'?','alef'),',',replace(@case,'?','bet'),' from t');

prepare stmt from @sql;

execute stmt;
```

Finally if you're really lazy ;) you can iterate through information_schema.columns view and dynamically create the select statement with s.t. along these lines:

```
set @subCase := '';
select @subCase := concat(@subCase,replace(@case,'?',column_name),',') from information_schema.columns where table_name = 't';
```

And these code can be probably safely wrapped in procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You need a separate `case` *expression* for each column in the result set:

```
select (case when cond1 then 'xyz' end) as col1, 
       (case when cond1 then 'xyz2' end) as col2, 
       (case when cond1 then 'uuy' end) as col3
```

A `case` expression returns only a single value.  You can use it to conditionally put different values in a single column based on one or more conditions:

```
select (case when cond1 then 'xyz'
             when cond2 then 'xyz2' 
             when cond3 then 'uuy'
         end) as col
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using UNION ALL.

E.g.

```
WITH my_original_resultset AS ( ... )
SELECT
  ... AS col1,
  ... AS col2,
  ... AS col3
FROM my_original_resultset
WHERE cond1
UNION ALL
SELECT
  ... AS col1,
  ... AS col2,
  ... AS col3
FROM my_original_resultset
WHERE cond2
```

Depending on your use case and the indexing, this may have performance implications (good or bad), but it fits the syntax you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You must use separated  case

```
case  when cond1 then 'xyz'  as col1 end, 
      when cond1 then 'xyz2' as col2 end, 
      when cond1 then 'uuy'  as col3 end
```